# how to solve sql_engine_core_inst.msi error in sql server installation

Tags: sql-server

**How to solve this problem ?**
I have an error while i install sql server.

> I have an error like "sql_engine_core_inst.msi  not found"

. How can i solve this problem. I already tried many things which is on internet.